# Laravel horizon long queue time

Tags: laravel, queue, ubuntu-18.04, laravel-horizon

I have problems with queue time in Laravel Horizon..

Case: I have an exam proctoring software that take picture from ~1500 students webcam every 30 seconds. Then I put it on the queue to broadcast via websocket the latest image to the teachers.

My server has 32 CPU and 192GB RAM.

Here is my horizon configuration:

[image: Horizon configuration]

And I receive some emails similar like this from the system. Varying from 1000 seconds to >30k seconds like this one.

The queue processing feels like very slow even when I put 100k maxProcesses..

[image: Email screenshot]

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance..

EDIT:
To make the question clearer here is the summary:

- My server has 32 CPU and 192GB RAM (Ubuntu 18.04).
- I allocated 100k max processes in horizon config (I even changed it yesterday to 1.000.000 max processes)
- BUT the queue processing is not as fast as I think it would. One of the queue even have 30k+ seconds wait time.
- How to make the queue processing faster? Is there any horizon/server configuration that I missed? Some limit configuration maybe in PHP Limit/Redis Limit/any limit?

Answer (score 3):

The following method is from horizon repository

```
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Horizon\Events\SupervisorLooped  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(SupervisorLooped $event)
{
    if (! $this->dueToMonitor()) {
        return;
    }

    // Here we will calculate the wait time in seconds for each of the queues that
    // the application is working. Then, we will filter the results to find the
    // queues with the longest wait times and raise events for each of these.
    $results = app(WaitTimeCalculator::class)->calculate();

    $long = collect($results)->filter(function ($wait, $queue) {
        return $wait > (config("horizon.waits.{$queue}") ?? 60);
    });

    // Once we have determined which queues have long wait times we will raise the
    // events for each of the queues. We'll need to separate the connection and
    // queue names into their own strings before we will fire off the events.
    $long->each(function ($wait, $queue) {
        [$connection, $queue] = explode(':', $queue, 2);

        event(new LongWaitDetected($connection, $queue, $wait));
    });
}
```

`LongWaitDetected` event triggering emails. "31941 seconds" is the waiting time of your `webcam` queue. Whenever `supervisor` starts looping it triggers `MonitorWaitTimes` and the code above works.

If you don't want to get this email, add your queue name into the your horizon config in the `waits` array with a huge number.

```
'waits' => [
    'redis:default' => 60,
    'redis:webcam' => 1514124141
],
```

But keep in mind that; it may be a sign that some of the processes/jobs are not working. 30K seconds may be an indication for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But my problem is not configuring the Wait Times.. I'm trying to figure out how to handle >100k queue in faster time.. Slow processing time leads to higher wait time.. I'll edit the question to make it clearer..